# Return to the previously opened application in PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, sharelink, web-share-target

I am working on developing a Progressive Web Application (PWA) that has a feature allowing it to receive URLs shared from other applications (using share-target api). Currently, when a user shares a URL with my PWA from another app, it automatically redirects them to my PWA. However, is it possible enables users to conveniently return to the previously used app by including a button in my PWA? (it would be better if doesn't redirect to my pwa)

For example in Wechat:

[image]

I researched on this. But didnt find anything